# Python relative imports creating unexpected behavior

Tags: python, python-import

I currently have a project with the following directory structure:

```
/reports/
  /supermart_reports/
    __init__.py
    load_check.py
    db_connection.py
    ahs_report/
      create_ahs_report.py
```

I call `create_ahs_report.py` from `reports/` using `python3.4 -m supermart_reports.ahs_report.create_ahs_report` and in that file I import both `db_connection` and `load_check` using `from ... import db_connection` and `from ... import load_check`. These imports seem to work. However, now when I run the script, in `load_check.py`, my line `import db_connection` is no longer working, saying `ImportError: No module named 'db_connection'`. What have I done to mess up the relative imports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When importing `db_connection` from `load_check`, use `from . import db_connection` or `import .db_connection`.
See https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html